# flashvars problem with cache buster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash

I am playing with a flash media player in rails app.

The problem is that flashvars parameter is very dumb.

Rails makes cache busters for url and it prevents flash from working.

```
flashvars="file=/my/media.flv?123456&autostart=false&repeat=none"
```

I had to change it to

```
flashvars="file=/my/media.flv&autostart=false&repeat=none"
```

Now I know how to work around but it feels very ad hoc. How do I fix it more elegantly?

Sam

Comment: URLEncode the string? Why not use SWFObject?

Comment: Hmm. So is the `?` throwing off your variables? Maybe you can make a separate flashvar for each of the bits of data - file, autostart, and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

To start with `file=/my/media.flv?123456&autostart=false&repeat=none` isn't a valid url, namely `?123456` is wrong. The query string should be in the format {key}={value}, whereas you just have a value.

Change the url to something similar to `file=/my/media.flv?id=123456&autostart=false&repeat=none` and rails should be able to generate a proper cache busting url.